# How to use Python3.5 in order to get around Python2.7 bug with cPickle?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle

I need to use Python3.x in order to work around the following bug with `cPickle`. The task needs to be completed soon.

I'm running into the following error using cPickle with `Python 2.7.10`. In fact, it's a bug which was only solved with Python3.x

http://bugs.python.org/issue11564

So, I installed Python3.5. Now, the script doesn't run, as I do not have modules installed for Python3, e.g.

```
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib
```

How should users begin downloading all the modules installed in Python 2.7 to Python 3.5?

Comment: Use `pip` to install packages for 3.5, or, if you're on Windows and running the python.org version of Python (i.e., not Anaconda or something else), you can download precompiled packages from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). You **can not** simply copy your `site-packages` directory from 2.7 to 3.5, you must reinstall everything fresh.

Comment: Your first question "How should users begin using both Python2.7 and Python 3.5?" is so broad as to be almost nonsensical, I don't know what you're asking for, so I've left it out of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze/) can do the work of mirroring package setups from one Python install to another.

Assuming `pip` is installed for both versions of Python (we'll name them `pip2` and `pip3`, you may need to use qualified paths to each depending on OS and configuration), you'd just do:

```
pip2 freeze > requirements.txt
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

That will install the same package and version for each package installed under the Py2 install in your Py3 install. See the [`pip freeze` docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_freeze/) for switches to tweak the output. I believe you could also delete the `==x.y.z` part of each requirement if you want the latest version instead of the same version.